# Battery Monitoring using voltage divider on ADC pin with STM32F030

Tags: microcontroller

Here i am new to  battery voltage monitoring using ADC for STM32F030.

i have some query related to battery monitoring  with ADC pin.

1) as mention in datasheet external input impedance(Rain) is 50k, how can i achieve matching impedance using voltage divider with minimum current drain.

2) how to calculate ADC Clock frequency for this STM32F030.

3) how capacitor help in matching impedance.

4) what value of resistor in divider should i have to select for matching impedance.

any document related to calculation of impedance matching than please share.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) as mention in datasheet external input impedance(Rain) is 50k, how
>   can i achieve matching impedance using voltage divider with minimum
>   current drain.

You don't need to 'match' an impedance. The 50k is the *maximum* input impedance at which the ADC's characteristics are guaranteed by the manufacturer.

Generally, you will want to have your voltage divider use as high resistance as possible to reduce current drain. Hence, you'd lay out the divider to have about 50kOhm of output impedance.

> 2) how to calculate ADC Clock frequency for this STM32F030.

Depends on how fast you want/need to sample and at what accuracy.

> 3) how capacitor help in matching impedance.

The ADC's input pin is not constantly sinking current. It only draws current from the signal source for a short moment each time a measurement is taken ([sample&hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold)).

Adding a capacitor to the ADC's input reduces the (AC!) *impedance* of the input signal as seen by the ADC during the brief moment it actually sinks current. This way, your signal's impedance can be much higher because it is not the instantaneous signal voltage that's measured (/loaded) but the voltage of the capacitor; after one measurement, the capacitor can be slowly (via the higher impedance voltage divider) charged back to the actual signal voltage to be ready for the next sampling.

Look up the capacitance of the S&H buffer in the ADC. Should be somewhere in the datasheet, in the order of a couple of pico Farad. Then select a capacitor of e.g. 100x-1000x that capacity and you should get pretty good measurements. (The bigger the external capacitor the less voltage drop at the moment of sampling, but a bigger capacitor takes longer to charge to close to the signal voltage so you can effectively trade accuracy for sampling speed.)

> 4) what value of resistor in divider should i have to select for matching impedance.

Fully depends on the battery's voltage and the max. ADC input voltage.

Comment: Good answer. If I recall correctly the 50k is at max sample rate so you can use an even higher input resistance if you sample slower. There is a formula in the data sheet.

Comment: My recollection is more that 50K would be for a slow conversion, with the impedance at fast rates being very low.  But that might have been a different STM32.   The capacitor idea is an interesting one; be sure to qualify the result against a real voltmeter, if you see any notable difference from loading before compensating that you may need to consider if that loading will vary under conditions of temperature, chip lot, etc.  Also make sure you are properly factoring out the supply voltage using the math to reference back to a reading of the internal bandgap.

Comment: Thank for your answer.